# How configure requests from other ports to port 443?

Tags: iptables, http, https, node.js

I am trying to configure my first https, and i think i get it, but there is a problem: the site wont open in http, just https, because of this, i want redirect everything to https.

I am using iptables, and this is my rules:[image]

This is my website: https://pubcrawlsp.com

Could someone give me a light here?

I already try use:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 443
```

I am using a EC2 instance, from amazon web services. [Ubuntu]

Comment: Despite what you say, it looks like now your HTTP site is available, but port 443 is closed.  If so, and you are not already using Apache, check the node.js documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/https.html.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use your firewall for this, use apache to do the redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost > 
<VirtualHost *:443> ServerName www.example.com

# ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

Comment: hm, do you know any tutorial that help me step by step Lain? I really don't know how to use apache

Answer (score 0):

Users might not expect port 80 to do HTTPS, so a HTTP redirect using Apache or node.js is at least going to be more conventional.

In answer to your direct question about iptables forwarding though, instead of your REDIRECT, you can see what happens if you try

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 54.207.73.169:443
```

(or whatever IP address you want to use.  Localhost should be fine if the server is bound to it.)